# Mock InfluxDB client to test a MetricCollector class

Tags: java, mockito, testng, influxdb

I have a metrics collector that store data on `InfluxDB`, I want to test the methods to store that metrics. I'm trying it but I'm not able to mock the `InfluxDB` client. I don't want to point to a real `InfluxDB` on the test environment.

Everything I've achieved so far are some "null pointer exceptions" and conection refused.

This is my test (using TestNG). What am I doing wrong?

```
    @Test
    public void validateMetrics() {
        String influxHost = "http://localhost";
        String credentials = "admin:admin";
        String influxDatabaseName = "testDataBase";
        influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(influxHost, credentials.split(":")[0], credentials.split(":")[1]);

        MetricsCollector metricsCollector = null;

        try {
            String hostName = "test-server-01";
            int statusValue = 1;
            metricsCollector = new MetricsCollector(influxDB);


            BatchPoints metrics = metricsCollector.initBatchPoint(influxDatabaseName); 
            Point point = metricsCollector.setMetric(hostName, "status", statusValue);
            metrics = metricsCollector.addToMetrics(metrics, point);

            Assert.assertTrue(metrics.getPoints().get(0).lineProtocol().contains(hostName));
            Assert.assertTrue(metrics.getPoints().get(0).lineProtocol().contains("status=" + statusValue));
        } finally {
           if (metricsCollector != null) {
                metricsCollector.closeConnection();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally misunderstanding how mockito works. Here is my fixed code:

```
    @Mock private InfluxDB influxDB;
    @Test
    public void validateMetrics() {
        MetricsCollector metricsCollector = null;
        String influxHost = "http://localhost";
        String credentials = "admin:admin";
        String influxDatabaseName = "testDataBase";

        influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(influxHost, credentials.split(":")[0], credentials.split(":")[1]);

       try {
            String hostName = "test-server-01";
            int statusValue = 1;
            metricsCollector = new MetricsCollector(influxDB);

            BatchPoints metrics = metricsCollector.initBatchPoint(influxDatabaseName); 
            Point point = metricsCollector.setMetric(hostName, "status", statusValue);
            metrics = metricsCollector.addToMetrics(metrics, point);

            Assert.assertTrue(metrics.getPoints().get(0).lineProtocol().contains(hostName));
            Assert.assertTrue(metrics.getPoints().get(0).lineProtocol().contains("status=" + statusValue));
       } finally {
           if (metricsCollector != null) {
                metricsCollector.closeConnection();
            }
       }
    }
```

Yep, added that simple "mock" annotation and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason you cannot mock the InfluxDB client is that it is created by a static method: `InfluxDBFactory.connect()`. To mock this you will need [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock).

Something like this:

```
@PrepareForTest({InfluxDBFactory.class})
public class ATestClass {

    @Test
    public void validateMetrics() {
        // this allows you to mock static methods on InfluxDBFactory
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(InfluxDBFactory.class);

        String influxHost = "http://localhost";
        String credentials = "admin:admin";
        String influxDatabaseName = "testDataBase";

        InfluxDB influxDB = Mockito.mock(InfluxDB.class);

        // when the connect() method is invoked in your test run it will return a mocked InfluxDB rather than a _real_ InfluxDB
        PowerMockito.when(InfluxDBFactory.connect(influxHost, credentials.split(":")[0], credentials.split(":")[1])).thenReturn(influxDB);

        // you won't do this in your test, I've only included it here to show you that InfluxDBFactory.connect() returns the mocked instance of InfluxDB
        InfluxDB actual = InfluxDBFactory.connect(influxHost, credentials.split(":")[0], credentials.split(":")[1]);
        Assert.assertSame(influxDB, actual);

        // the rest of your test
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note: there are specific compatability requirements for TestNG, Mockito and PowerMock described [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions) and [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven#TestNG).

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, but you put me in the right way. I will edit the question and add the solution. Thanks